# Implementing a Stack in C++ using a linked list

Tags: c++, function, methods, linked-list, stack

So I am trying to implement a Stack using a linked list and classes. Right now I have 6 different files: node.h, node.cpp, LL.h, LL.cpp, Stack.h, and Stack.cpp. I want to complete the Stack.h and Stack.cpp files so that they work as they should. I already implemented the linked list functions and they work as they should. Here is the code:

node.h :

```
// node.h

class node { // node class used in the LL (linked list) class
    private:
        node * next; // Pointer to next node of an LL
        int data;    // integer data stored in this node

    public:
        node(int x, node * n);  // Constructor
        ~node();                // Destructor
        void set_data(int x);   // Change the data of this node
        void set_next(node * n);// Change the next pointer of this node
        int get_data();         // Access the data of this node
        node * get_next();      // Access the next pointer of this node
};
```

LL.h :

```
// LL.h
#include "node.h"

// Linked list class, used in the Stack class
class LL {
    private:
        node * head; // pointer to first node
        node * tail; // pointer to last node

    public:
        LL(); // Constructor
        ~LL(); // Destructor
        void prepend(int value); // add a node to the beginning of the LL
        int removeHead();        // remove the first node of the LL
        void print();            // print the elements of the LL
    node * get_head();       // access the pointer to the first node of the LL
};
```

Stack.h:

```
// Stack.h
#include "LL.h"

class Stack {
private:
    LL_t intlist;

public:

    Stack();    // Constructor
    ~Stack();       // Destructor

    void push(int value);
    int pop();      
    int isEmpty();
    void print();
};
```

And lastly,
Stack.cpp:

```
// Stack.cpp
#include "Stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>

Stack::Stack() {
    head= NULL;
    tail= NULL;
}

Stack::~Stack() {
    delete intlist;
}

int Stack::isEmpty() {
    return (head==NULL);
}

void Stack::push(int value) {

    head= value;
}

int Stack::pop() {

    if ( !isEmpty() ) {
        int temp= tail->get_data();
        delete tail;
        return temp;    
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I am having compiling issues. It says get_data() is undefined and "head" and "tail" is undefined, even though I have " #include "LL.h" " in Stack.h and in LL.h, I have "#include "node.h" ", so they all build on one another so it should work correct? I want it to compile so I can see if I am implementing Stack.h and Stack.cpp correctly. Do you see any issues with the way I am implementing them? If so, can you point them out? Also, any idea as to why I am getting these compiling issues? Any help appreciated!

Comment: How do you compile/link all those files together ? Could send the command line ? forget the question if you used an IDE, but check if you link all the files

Comment: Offtopic: You should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`); get used to implementing constructors initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`): `LL() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) { }`; in case of complex objects, you avoid default initialisation + later assignment (both might be expensive) in favour to direct initialisation right in the constructor; some types (references, types without default constructor) *only* can be initialised this way.

Comment: `head` and `tail` are not members of `Stack`. You're supposed to use the list interface, not its members. (I suspect that you've skipped ahead too far in your fine C++ book.)

Comment: Also, there is no type called "LL_t ".

Comment: `intlist` is *not* a pointer, so you cannot delete it in destructor! Be aware that the list's destructor is called *implicitly* on calling the stack's destructor.

Comment: It looks like you tried to tailor your linked list class to fit a stack class.  That is not the way it should be -- your linked list class should simply have the basic operations -- add a node *anywhere* in the list, remove a node from *anywhere* in the list, etc., and not try to "cheat" by making the linked list class a stack class by only having "prepend", removeHead, etc. In other words, pretend that a stack class doesn't exist at all when implementing the linked list.  Once you have the linked list class coded, *then* you implement the stack using the basic operations of the linked list.

Comment: ...and before starting to code the stack class, make sure your linked list works properly.

Comment: Off-topic: There are so many ways how a linked list could be printed, so many different formats. And there are so many different targets possible (`std::cout`, files, into a string or character array for later use, ...). I recommend rather not including such a `print` function into the classes, imposing one specific implemenation to the users. Rather let *them* decide how and to where to print.

Comment: Are you aware that there's a `bool` type in C++? You should prefer it over `int` if you just want to indicate success or error (e. g. `LL::removeHead`). With int, there are too many ambiguities: some use 1 for success, 0 for error (e. g. winAPI), others 0 for success, negative for error (most POSIX functions), and you opted for a mixture of the former two...

Comment: Dangerous: `node::set_next` is public, but you allow access to the list's nodes (`getHead`!). So users could easily break the list (e. g. setting some `next` to nullptr – while this node is not the true tail, which still points to the original node – and the nodes in between are leaking). Better: make `set_next` private and give `LL` access to via friendship. Even better: nodes are closely related to the concept of linked lists (and trees, too, but for these, the node types differ – as would for doubly linked list), so they can be considered implementation detail --> make them a nested class.

Comment: You could also simply use [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) instead of reimplementing your own

Comment: Thank you everyone who commented. I understand the errors now. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at your actual questions

```
Stack::Stack() {
    head= NULL;
    tail= NULL;
}
```

results in error `"head" and "tail" is undefined`. Now look at the header files, where are the declarations of `head` and `tail`? Answer, in the `LL` class not the `Stack` class. It's the responsibility of the `LL` class to initialise `head` and `tail` which it does the in the `LL` class default constructor. So your `Stack` constructor should look like this

```
Stack::Stack() {
}
```

Whenever you have a constructor for a class which contains another class a constructor for the other class will be called. In the case of `Stack` the default constuctor for `LL` is called implicitly, and this initialises `head` and `tail` for you. You don't have to do anything.

Now lets look at some more of your implementation.

```
Stack::~Stack() {
    delete intlist;
}
```

`intList` is not a pointer, so it cannot be deleted. It's clear that you are trying to 'call` the destructor for your list, but just like the constructor this happens automatically. Your destructor should look like this

```
Stack::~Stack() {
}
```

Or you could (probably should) just remove it completely.

Moving on

```
int Stack::isEmpty() {
    return (head==NULL);
}
```

Again you are trying to access `head` somewhere it isn't accessible. Your `Stack` class has an `LL intlist` object and that's what it should use, so (for instance)

```
int Stack::isEmpty() {
    return intlist.get_head() == NULL;
}
```

Smae thing here

```
void Stack::push(int value) {
    head= value;
}
```

should be

```
void Stack::push(int value) {
    intlist.prepend(value);
}
```

Use the object that the stack has (the `intlist`) not the internals of other objects.

I'll leave you do sort out the rest. But you must understand the division of responsbilities that exist in your class design. The `Stack` class should not (and cannot) concern itself with the internals of the `LL` class. All that the operations that `Stack` needs to perform should be doable with the public interface of the `LL` class. If not then it's the `LL` class that needs to change.

Also note that your `pop` implementation is not just wrong in executuion it's wrong in concept. `Pop` should remove the **head** of the list, not the tail. A stack is a LIFO list (last in, first out) so `pop` removes the most recentaly added item. Now looking at the `LL` class there is a `removeHead` method (hint, hint).

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand everything so much better now. Really appreciate it

Comment: After implementing all the suggestions, I am getting a Segmentation fault. Do you know why that might be the case?

Comment: @john There are hundreds of ways to cause a segmentation fault so without seeing your code it's impossiblle to say. You should ask a new question with your latest code.

Comment: @john I can't see any new code. In any case you should ask a **new** question, not edit this question.

Comment: Yea you're right I ended up deleting it from this question and asking a new question instead. Thanks anyway :)